# Blog posts by former staff members are missing attribution

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, stack-exchange-team

Certain blog posts written by members of staff that are no longer with the company seem to be missing the attribution for posts that they wrote. For instance, [JNat and animuson: workin' on ur problemz](https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/04/22/jnat-and-animuson-workin-on-ur-problemz/) is blank in the "author" section, instead of showing that [hairboat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/165581/hairboat) wrote it:

[image: Blank "authors" section]

It did [used to](https://web.archive.org/web/20230203033149/https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/04/22/jnat-and-animuson-workin-on-ur-problemz/) show the proper attribution.

Another example of a post missing the author is [Stack Gives Back 2022](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/01/12/stack-gives-back-2022/), posted in January of this year (2023). It was written by [Nicolas Chabanovsky](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/274323/nicolas-chabanovsky) but displays no authorship - in the past it displayed the author as "Nicolas Chabanovskii".

Some posts by former staff do show the authorship properly, though, such as [A Day in the Penalty Box](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) by Jeff Atwood.

While I don't know the ins-and-outs of the copyright and license of posts on the blog, the authors should still be displayed.

Comment: Another related bug, when the author is showing, it's not a link anymore, it used to link to the author page on the blog with some details and list of their blog posts.

Comment: @ShadowTheGPTWizard this is in our backlog to evaluate adding author pages (vs say a more advanced search experience). Worth pointing out bios are now included in the sidebar if we have them e.g., https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/08/23/fitting-ai-models-in-your-pocket-with-quantization/

Comment: @David thanks, having way to see all posts by specific author is pretty useful so hope it will be brought back in some way or another.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This one should be fixed now. It affected around older 100 posts by a few authors. Please let me know if you spot any others.